# Alignment Issue After OnClick Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a recent scores section for a sports league website that I currently operate. Recently, I added in scroll sections on either side so users can scroll back and forth between previous and future games.

That part worked out just fine, but I noticed that there is a slight alignment issue after I implemented the scroll sections. Underneath the game section, there is a drop down bar which displays the users participating in all of the games that are displayed.

Once that drop down bar is clicked, the alignment goes completely wacky and squashes everything to the right. I've been trying to figure this out for several hours, but I have come up completely empty.

You can check out what I'm talking about by visiting the following link:

http://xbox-sports.com/leagues/new_xbshl/

Any and all help would be much appreciated!

Comment: it looks like it's lining up with the drop down table. Have you tried placing the dropdown table in it's own table?

Comment: I didn't even think of doing that. Thank you!